# C# code to run my installer.exe file in silent mode, in the background,

Tags: c#, cmd, silent-installer

I have this C# code:

```
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.Arguments = "–s –v –qn";
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.FileName = desktopPath + "\\" + "MyInstaller_7.1.51.14.exe";
Process.Start(psi);
```

The first line simply grabs the path of my desktop and the rest attempts to run an installer exe file in silent mode. By silent mode I mean, in the background, without the install wizard, or any UI of any sort during installation. The `–s –v –qn` arguments are there so that that the installation runs in silent mode.

The problem is that when I run the command equivalent of the above in the command prompt, which is this:

```
C:\Users\ME\Desktop>MyInstaller_7.1.51.14.exe -s -v -qn
```

The installer runs as wanted, in silent mode.

Unfortunately, the problem is that trying the same thing in C# with the above code does NOT run the installer in silent mode. The installation wizard DOES appear, which is **BAD** for by purposes.

I'm thinking maybe I need to run this like a service via C# or under the 0 id of the users. Or with an -i switch. I'm not really sure. Can anyone help??

Just for clarification, my question is, how do I write C# code to run my installer.exe file in silent mode, in the background, with no visible UI?

Please help.

Comment: What product did you use to create the installer?  Not that it should matter, but it might help someone reproduce it.

Comment: Did you think to create temp BAT file with this command in it `C:\Users\...\Temp\MyInstaller_7.1.51.14.exe -s -v -qn` and run that?

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct answer:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.Arguments = "/s /v /qn /min";
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.FileName = newRenamedFile;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start(psi);
```

The issue was the switches were missing the forward slashes.